# Tone to use in describing your "research project"

Tags: phd, masters, writing, application-cover-letter

This is an extension question for this [What exactly is "briefly explain your master research project" in a PhD application? (CS field)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158407/what-exactly-is-briefly-explain-your-master-research-project-in-a-phd-applicat/158408?noredirect=1#comment423203_158408)

Suppose I am writing a brief description for my research project (for my phD application), **should I be using some "higher level" vocabulary or easy understanding words?** This is because I don't know whether the admission committee will understand ...

Will there be different between a master and a phD when describing the research experience?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you don't know whether an admissions committee made up of some of the most qualified and experienced people in your field will understand some difficult words?

Comment: ?! so if I'm applying for CS, the admission committee are the people who hold a CS related degree???

Comment: @GarlicSTAT The admissions committee will be made up of professors in the program you apply to.

Comment: !! Really?! So it's not like undergraduate where the admission committee are "general" people?

Comment: The admissions committee for PhD is the faculty of the department where you are applying. So these are people who are professors in CS (in your case). You should write using words that are understandable to CS faculty, but not necessarily people who have published in your precise area.

Comment: @GarlicSTAT Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/917/who-typically-serves-on-a-graduate-school-admissions-committee